# Error while installing Solargraph extension in VSCode

Tags: ruby, macos

I just started learning Ruby and was setting up VSCode for working with it, when I ran into a bit of a weird situation with the Solargraph extension. I installed solargraph via `gem install solargraph` and everything seemed to go through, no errors.
However, after installing the extension itself in VSCode I get the following errors

"Solargraph not found. Run `gem install solargraph` or update your Gemfile."

As well as

"Couldn't start Ruby Language Server".

Moreover, when I enter the command `solargraph -v` I get an error saying solargraph can't be found.

I'm not really familiar at all with how Ruby or gems work, so I'm kinda lost. How can it not be found when it gets installed without a problem?

I use macOS if that's relevant.

Comment: Perhaps you are using a ruby version manager and switched to a different version from the one on which you installed the gem?

Answer (score 0):

I was constantly getting this message. For me, uninstalling and reinstalling worked:

```bash
gem uninstall solargraph
gem install solargraph
```

Note: it asked whether I want to uninstall the executable too, I selected `Y`.

Idea from [here](https://github.com/castwide/vscode-solargraph/issues/108#issuecomment-599728681), it shows some extra steps which I didn't need but may be useful.